# XOR in shell globs

Tags: bash, wildcards

Recently my hosting provider changed my `public_html` directory's name to `www` without me knowing it so this variable declaration `web_application_root="${HOME}/public_html"` no longer works.

For similar future cases, not necessarily in that hosting environment, I want to instruct Bash to create a variable based on `public_html"` XOR `www`.

If and how would that be possible?

Comment: I am not sure how the XOR operator applies to strings. Can you elaborate? Perhaps you mean "web_application_root gets assigned the value *public_html* or *www*, depending on the name of the directory in $HOME". If so, a simple `if [ -d $HOME/www]; then ...; else ...; fi` does the trick.

Comment: @berndbausch In case the string represents a directory name; only one of the two directory names (i.e the one which extists) should be picked.

Comment: That's what I guessed. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do better than

```
web_application_root="${HOME}/public_html"
if [ ! -d "$web_application_root" ] ; then
   web_application_root="${HOME}/www"
fi
```

in various guises. e.g.

```
for loc in "${HOME}/public_html" "${HOME}/www" ; do
   web_application_root=$loc
   [ -d "$loc" ] && break
done
```

Essentially find the first directory which exists and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer the question in the subject here.

Globbing is the expansion of a wildcard pattern such as `*.txt` into the list of file paths matching them.

```
files=(~/*.txt)
```

assigns the list of non-hidden files in `~` whose name ends in `.txt` as separate elements of the `$files` array (with variation in behaviour between shells when the glob doesn't match any file).

`XOR(A, B)` is true if `A` or `B` are true but not both, so is like `AND(OR(A, B), NOT(AND(A, B)))`

While I don't know of any shell that has a `XOR` glob/wildcard operator, several shells have a `OR` and `NOT`, which means `AND` (where `AND(X, Y)` can also be written `NOT(OR(NOT(X), NOT(Y)))` can also be expressed there and as a result `XOR` as well (zsh also has a `AND-NOT`, which makes `AND` `AND-NOT(X, NOT(Y))`).

If we combine those formulas, we get:

```
XOR(A, B) == NOT(OR(NOT(OR(A, B)), NOT(NOT(NOT(OR(NOT(A), NOT(B)))))))
```

Which we can simplify (removing the double-negation) to:

```
XOR(A, B) == NOT(OR(NOT(OR(A, B)), NOT(OR(NOT(A), NOT(B)))))
```

Once translated to `ksh` or `bash -o extglob` (or `zsh -o kshglob`) globs, that becomes:

```
!(!(A|B)|!(!(A)|!(B)))
```

Or with `zsh -o extendedglob` globs:

```
^(^(A|B)|^(^A|^B))
```

Or using `AND-NOT`:

```
XOR(A, B) == AND-NOT(OR(A, B), NOT(NOT(AND-NOT(A, NOT(B)))))
```

Which we can simplify to:

```
XOR(A, B) == AND-NOT(OR(A, B), AND-NOT(A, NOT(B)))
```

Which once translated to `zsh -o extendedglob` globs:

```
(A|B)~(A~^B)
```

So for instance, to find files that match `foo*` and `*.txt`, but not both, you could:

with `ksh` or `bash -o extglob` (or `zsh -o kshglob`):

```
files=(!(!(foo*|*.txt)|!(!(foo*)|!(*.txt))))
```

Or with `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
files=(^(^(foo*|*.txt)|^(^foo*|^*.txt)))
```

Or:

```
files=((foo*|*.txt)~(foo*~^*.txt))
```

POSIX shells have a binary (bitwise) XOR arithmetic operator: `$(( 1 ^ 2 ))` expands to `3` because that's `XOR(0b01, 0b10)`.

So you could define a `xor` function that returns true if either but not both the evaluation of two pieces of shell code return true with something like:

```
xor() {
  eval "$1"; s1=$((!$?))
  eval "$2"; s2=$((!$?))
  [ "$((s1 ^ s2))" -ne 0 ]
}
match() {
  case $1 in
    ($2) true;;
    (*)  false;;
  esac
}
for file in *; do
  if
    xor 'match "$file" "foo*"' \
        'match "$file" "*.txt"' &&
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
  fi
done
```